# Php sort multi associative array based on specific key

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array

I have the following array $data:

```
 [args]=>array
   (
       [data]=>array
          (
            [num]=>8813332
            [bask]=>sell
            [end]=>09263013
          )

        [cust_data]=>array
          (
            [name]=>john
            [id]=>784
            [state]=>New York
          )

         [pre_job]=>array
           (
              [0]=>array
                (
                   [name]=>bk
                   [label]=>base
                   [type]=>PDF
                )

               [1]=>array
                 (
                    [name]=>fr
                    [label]=>front
                    [type]=>PDF
                 )
           )

   )
```

I basically want to be able to sort the array inside of pre_jobs to have the whatever is named as fr be the first and whatever is named bk be the last

At times this array may come in sorted the way i want and at times it wont so I need to be able to check and sort according to 'name' and have it sort with fr first then bk

Any idea.

I saw this function but now sure what it even does

```
    function cmp($a,$b){
       return strcmp($a,$b);
    }

    usort($data_data['args']['pre_jobs'], "cmp");
```

Comment: If you have only two elements (arrays) in `pre_job` you don't need usort - just check which is first and if needed switch places. Anyways, changing "first" and "last" elements in an array is not considered as "sorting"

Comment: I may have more than 2 elements in pre_job but I know these two most likely exist along with the others

Comment: the condition that you gave here is a good condition for the first and last elements - you can't SORT an array of more than 3 elements by using it!